# CSS height calculation doesn't add up

Tags: css

I have the following code:

```
<div id="headerwrap">
 <div id="headertop">aaa</div>
 <div id="headermiddle">abc</div>
 <div id="headerbottom">def</div>
</div>
#headerwrap      { position:fixed; top:0; left:0; } 
#headertop       { height:55px; margin:0 auto; }
#headermiddle    { height:25px; margin:0 auto; }
#headerbottom    { height:9px; margin:0 auto; }
```

I am trying to follow the header with a fixed position . When I do this I find an overlap. Checking with firebug I find the following:

```
headerwrap height - 91px
headertop height - 55px
headermiddle height - 25px
headerbottom height - 9px
```

Can anyone explain to me why the numbers don't add up? This is giving me position problems and I can't see what's wrong.

Why does 55+25+9 add up to 91?

Comment: I have to ask, why are you doing this with no actual "real" data? Is it because you want to position everything inside with position absolute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get `89px`, here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/cBPNg/).

Are you sure that's all the CSS and that there aren't borders or extra styles on any of the elements?

**EDIT:** Just seen your comment on the other answer :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to try a demo :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the content in #headerbottom isn't taller than 9px? You might need to use `overflow-y: hidden;`

By the way, with that code, headerwrap should have the same height as headertop, it shouldn't be the sum of the others, because 9 + 25 is not greater than 55.

Comment: More looking and I found my answer. How embarrassing. What was causing the numbers to be different was that I had a 1px border at the top and bottom of headermiddle. Seems like Firebug shows height of the object but does not include the border height.